Update records in a table using azure function time trigger in nodejs
I want to update the records in a SQL server table.
The query looks like this:
UPDATE TutorAds
SET Status = 'expired', Published_At = NULL
WHERE Published_At < DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())

But I could not find good example of updating records after 1 day.
I am following this Microsoft guide.
Previously I have tried to do it like this, but it only updates the table record when I run the function locally. After deployment, it is not changing the DB.
Here is my function code in VSCODE:
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');
const { Connection, Request } = require('tedious');
require('dotenv').config();

app.timer('newtriggerexpre', {
    schedule: '0 */2 * * * *',
    handler: (myTimer, context) => {
        const config = {
            "server": process.env.SQL_SERVER,
            "authentication": {
                "type": "default",
                "options": {
                    "userName": process.env.SQL_USERNAME,
                    "password": process.env.SQL_PASSWORD
                }
            },
            "options": {
                "port": 1433,
                "database": "Tutoringacademy",
                "trustServerCertificate": true
            }
        }

        const connection = new Connection(config);

        // Connect to SQL Server
        connection.on('connect', async function (err) {
            if (err) {
                context.log.error(err);
                return;
            }

            try {
                // Calculate the date 7 days ago
                const sevenDaysAgo = new Date();
                sevenDaysAgo.setDate(sevenDaysAgo.getDate() - 7);

                // Execute update query for records older than 7 days
                const request = new Request(`
                UPDATE TutorAds
                SET Status = 'expired', Published_At = NULL
                WHERE Published_At < DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE())
                `, function (err, rowCount) {
                    if (err) {
                        context.log.error(err);
                        return;
                    }

                    context.log(`${rowCount} rows were updated`);
                });

                request.addParameter('sevenDaysAgo', TYPES.DateTime, sevenDaysAgo);

                connection.execSql(request);
            } catch (err) {
                context.log.error(err);
            }
        });
    }
});




Have you added the SQL_SERVER, SQL_USERNAME and SQL_PASSWORD in the function app > Environment variables in Azure Portal?

You are attempting to add a parameter (sevenDaysAgo) to the request, but you're not using it in your query. You're directly using DATEADD(DAY, -7, GETDATE()) in the query instead of the parameter.
Here is the updated code with the above parameter with the timer trigger function.
Code :
const { app } = require('@azure/functions');
const { Connection, Request, TYPES } = require('tedious');
require('dotenv').config();

app.timer('newtriggerexpre', {
    schedule: '0 */2 * * * *',
    handler: async (myTimer, context) => {
        const config = {
            "server": process.env.SQL_SERVER,
            "authentication": {
                "type": "default",
                "options": {
                    "userName": process.env.SQL_USERNAME,
                    "password": process.env.SQL_PASSWORD
                }
            },
            "options": {
                "port": 1433,
                "database": "Tutoringacademy",
                "trustServerCertificate": true
            }
        }
        
        const connection = new Connection(config);
        connection.on('connect', async function (err) {
            if (err) {
                context.log.error(err);
                return;
            }

            try {
                const sevenDaysAgo = new Date();
                sevenDaysAgo.setDate(sevenDaysAgo.getDate() - 7);
                const request = new Request(`
                UPDATE TutorAds
                SET Status = 'expired', Published_At = NULL
                WHERE Published_At < @sevenDaysAgo
                `, function (err, rowCount) {
                    if (err) {
                        context.log.error(err);
                        return;
                    }
                    context.log(`${rowCount} rows were updated`);
                    connection.close(); 
                });
                request.addParameter('sevenDaysAgo', TYPES.DateTime, sevenDaysAgo);
                connection.execSql(request);
            } catch (err) {
                context.log.error(err);
            }
        });
    }
});

local.settings.json :
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "storage_connec",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "node",
    "AzureWebJobsFeatureFlags": "EnableWorkerIndexing",
    "SQL_SERVER": "<server_name>.database.windows.net",
    "SQL_USERNAME": "<user_name>",
    "SQL_PASSWORD": "<password>"
  }
}

Output :
The timer trigger function ran successfully as below,

Make sure that your Azure Function is properly deployed and that the environment variables SQL_SERVER, SQL_USERNAME and  SQL_PASSWORD as shown below,

Azure Portal :


